# Batch that lists files names in folder in txt file line by line

Tags: batch, batch-file

I need a batch file that will make list of files in directory of batch file, but must complete these requirements:
-List can't contain record of that .bat
-there will be hundreds to thousands files 
-list must be line by line, file name by file name 
Files are in JPG or Png extension 
Sorry for my English, and I hope you will help me

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /b *.jpg > filelist.txt && dir /b *.png >> filelist.txt
```